# update values into FILE_1 using values for matching key from FILE_2 with bash - maybe awk

Tags: awk

I have the following situation:
FILE_1 which contains a ddl and it could be like this:

```
column_A  varchar(50)
column_B  int
column_C  varchar (100)
```

and FILE_2 which contains what is changed in FILE_1, for example

```
column_B  varchar(50)
```

I would like to update FILE_1 changing from "column_B  int" to "column_B  varchar(50)"
and of course I would need also all other line unchanged

using awk I managed to identify the changed line

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} ($1 in a)' file_1 file_2
```

but I don't know how I can write it into file_1

how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){$2=a[$1]} 1' file_2 file_1
```

In case above command is printing correct results for you on terminal then you could use following which will save output into Input_file itself.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} ($1 in a)' file_1 file_2 > temp && mv temp file_1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{            ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be true when first Input_file named file_2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$2          ##Creating array a with index of $1 and its value is $2 from current line.
  next              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){          ##Checking condition if first field is present in array a then do following.
  $2=a[$1]          ##Assigning array a value with index of first field to 2nd field.
}
1                   ##1 will print current line here.
' file_2 file_1     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```